VS Code: Reopen last project if it wasn't closed manually
It looks like one of the recent versions of VS Code changed the behavior related to closing the app.
Before, when opening the VS Code, I'd have my previous session restored if there was anything open before closing. But if I closed the session (cmd+W on mac) and then reopened, it would start clean.
Did they change it? Now, no matter what I do, it always opens the last session and it's annoying. I know there's window.restoreWindows setting, but none of its values seem to reproduce how it behaved before.
Can I somehow make it VS Code forget about the previous session if I close it manually?

This question is similar to: How to prevent Visual Studio Code from always reopening the previous files or folders?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.   (I know this question is asking the opposite....)

@Luuk I made it clear enough that it's something else.

Did they change it? ... I am not a VS Code user, but one would have to review the release notes of the past few releases to truly know, but perhaps there is a related setting in the project save options like other IDE's?

@PaulT. I think it could also be related to the macOS update. Perhaps mac changed something about the way closing windows works? Anyway it looks too nuanced to have its dedicated VS Code setting, but maybe I'm wrong.

Looks like it may have been part of this release change last month? https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_96, then search the page for: Restore Edit sessions after restart. However, no mention of a related preference setting, so apparently it's not configurable, which is unfortunate.

@PaulT. that's about the copilot extension

@starball Ok, thanks!
